# Switch between vertical and horizontal stepper material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How to switch between **mat-vertical-stepper** and **mat-horizontal-stepper** from angular component with same stepper steps?

Comment: It is one of the wonders of creation that angular doesn't just use mat-stepper and avoid all this horizontal-vertical distin. The current approach makes responsiveness too long of a process. Ooh Angular ....

Answer (score 18):

to avoid rewriting identical html content, do like this. Create the template and give them a reference using a `#hashtag`. then you can instert them using `ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="hashtag"></ng-container>`.

here is an example of making a responsive stepepr, the angular material way.

```
<ng-template #stepOne>
  <div>step one</div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #stepTwo>
  <div>step two</div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #stepThree>
  <div>step three</div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #stepFour>
  <div>step four</div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template [ngIf]="smallScreen" [ngIfElse]="bigScreen">
  <mat-vertical-stepper linear #stepper >
    <mat-step>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stepOne"></ng-container>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stepTwo"></ng-container>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stepThree"></ng-container>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stepFour"></ng-container>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-vertical-stepper>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #bigScreen>
  <mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper >
    <mat-step>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stepOne"></ng-container>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step >
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stepTwo"></ng-container>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stepThree"></ng-container>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stepFour"></ng-container>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
</ng-template>
```

You can use the angular cdk layout to track screen size like this.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints} from '@angular/cdk/layout';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-responsive-stepper',
  templateUrl: './responsive-stepper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./responsive-stepper.component.scss']
})
export class ResponsiveStepperComponent implements OnInit {

    smallScreen: boolean;

    constructor(
       private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver
      ) {
        breakpointObserver.observe([
          Breakpoints.XSmall,
          Breakpoints.Small
        ]).subscribe(result => {
          this.smallScreen = result.matches;
      });
     }
}
```

Comment: Will not work if you put inside ng-template matStepperNext, matStepLabel etc.
So it's not a real used solution

Comment: if you want a stepper in the template change from `matStepperNext` to `(click)="stepper.next()"`, and you can place `matStepLabel` before `ng-container`

Answer (score 8):

I use [Teradata's Covalent](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components) components alongside Google's Material components. They use material design and the modules are even imported in the same manner as Google's material modules.

Covalent's stepper is setup with a mode input in mind so you would implement the HTML template like this:

```
<td-steps [mode]="stepperMode">
  <td-step>
    ...
  </td-step>
  ...
</td-steps>
```

Then in your component's typescript file you can setup the variable to be either horizontal or vertical according to your needs:

```
if (condition) {
  stepperMode = 'horizontal';
} else {
  stepperMode = 'vertical';
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Since Angular 12 (specifically these PRs: https://github.com/angular/components/pull/21940 and https://github.com/angular/components/pull/22139) you can now just use [**`MatStepper`**](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api#MatStepper) (note that both [**`MatHorizontalStepper`**](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api#MatHorizontalStepper) and [**`MatVerticalStepper`**](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api#MatVerticalStepper) were deprecated in these PRs) and set orientation input as you need:

```
<mat-stepper [orientation]="orientation">
  <mat-step>Step 1</mat-step>
  <mat-step>Step 2</mat-step>
</mat-stepper>
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxxpif)

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to do the same thing and finally figured out how to get it to work, with complete transclusion for the steps, etc, plus you can sync the currently-selected index between the horizontal and vertical so that the page size changing won't reset the person back to step 1.

Here's a complete example.

Wrapper component HTML:

```
<ng-template #horizontal>
  <mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper
    [linear]="isLinear"
    (selectionChange)="selectionChanged($event)">
    <mat-step *ngFor="let step of steps; let i = index"
      [stepControl]="step.form"
      [label]="step.label"
      [optional]="step.isOptional">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="step.template"></ng-container>
      <div class="actions">
        <div class="previous">
          <button *ngIf="i > 0" 
            type="button" mat-button
            color="accent"
            (click)="reset()"
            matTooltip="All entries will be cleared">Start Over</button>
          <button *ngIf="i > 0"
            type="button" mat-button
            matStepperPrevious>Previous</button>
        </div>
        <div class="next">
          <button type="button" mat-button
            color="primary"
            matStepperNext
            (click)="step.submit()">{{i === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}}</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #vertical>
  <mat-vertical-stepper #stepper
    [linear]="isLinear"
    (selectionChange)="selectionChanged($event)">
    <mat-step *ngFor="let step of steps; let i = index"
      [stepControl]="step.form"
      [label]="step.label"
      [optional]="step.isOptional">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="step.template"></ng-container>
      <div class="actions">
        <div class="previous">
          <button *ngIf="i > 0" 
            type="button" mat-button
            color="accent"
            (click)="reset()"
            matTooltip="All entries will be cleared">Start Over</button>
          <button *ngIf="i > 0"
            type="button" mat-button
            matStepperPrevious>Previous</button>
        </div>
        <div class="next">
          <button type="button" mat-button
            color="primary"
            matStepperNext
            (click)="step.submit()">{{i === steps.length - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}}</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-vertical-stepper>
</ng-template>
```

Wrapper component ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input, ContentChildren, QueryList, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, BreakpointState } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { StepComponent } from './step/step.component';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { MatStepper } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'stepper',
  templateUrl: './stepper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stepper.component.scss']
})
export class StepperComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public selectedIndex: number = 0;
  public isMobile: boolean;
  public template: TemplateRef<any>;
  @Input() isLinear: boolean = true;
  @Input() startAtIndex: number;
  @ContentChildren(StepComponent) private steps: QueryList<StepComponent>;
  @ViewChild('horizontal') templHorizontal: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('vertical') templVertical: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatStepper;

  private _bpSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private bpObserver: BreakpointObserver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._bpSub = this.bpObserver
      .observe(['(max-width: 599px)'])
      .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
        this.setMobileStepper(state.matches);
      });

    if (this.startAtIndex) {
      this.selectedIndex = this.startAtIndex;
    }
  }

  selectionChanged(event: any): void {
    this.selectedIndex = event.selectedIndex;
  }

  setMobileStepper(isMobile: boolean): void {
    this.isMobile = isMobile;
    if (isMobile) {
      this.template = this.templVertical;
    }
    else {
      this.template = this.templHorizontal;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      // need async call since the ViewChild isn't ready
      // until after this function runs, thus the setTimeout hack
      this.stepper.selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
    });
  }

  reset(): void {
    this.stepper.reset();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._bpSub.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Step component HTML:

```
<ng-template #template>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

Step component ts:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, TemplateRef, ViewChild, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'stepper-step',
  templateUrl: './step.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./step.component.scss']
})
export class StepComponent {

  @Input() isOptional: boolean = false;
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  @ViewChild('template') template: TemplateRef<any>;
  @Output() formSubmitted: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  submit(): void {
    this.formSubmitted.emit(this.form.value);
  }

}
```

Using responsive Angular Material Stepper in component HTML:

```
<stepper>
  <stepper-step
    label="Step 1 label"
    [form]="step1form"
    (formSubmitted)="form1Submit($event)">
    content
    <form [formGroup]="frmStep1">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput name="firstname" formControlName="firstname" placeholder="First Name" />
      </mat-form-field>
      content
    </form>
  </stepper-step>
  <stepper-step
    label="Step 2 label"
    [form]="step2form">
    step 2 content
  </stepper-step>
</stepper>
```

And the component function needed for forms:

```
form1Submit(formValues: any): void {
  console.log(formValues);
}
```

Comment: Thats really great, thanks a lot. But in the wrapper component HTML you forgot the template inclusion: `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>`

Comment: Very nice, well done. But for me this still is not perfect. 

See in this example https://stackblitz.com/angular/egkmmebdyyq?file=app%2Fstepper-optional-example.ts - when step two is clicked without filling out step one, mat-error of step one gets triggered. This behavior does not exist in your version it seems. I have copied down you example and added required validatiors to the form group - and this behavior does not exist..... Would you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Sounds correct.  I was mainly interested here in showing how to make the component responsive and not reset the person's progress.  Obviously form validation will need to be taken into account as each setup might be different, some allowing you to go to another step without finishing one whereas typically it will probably be like you outline.  Looks like you took care of that part for your case.

Comment: I found a way. In your StepComponent you have `@Input() form: FormGroup;`, you should change this to two way binding something like this `formGroupValue: FormGroup;
    @Input()
    get formGroup() {
        return this.formGroupValue;
    }
    @Output() formGroupChange = new EventEmitter();
    set formGroup(value) {
        this.formGroupValue = value;
        this.formGroupChange.emit(this.formGroupValue);
    }` (https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html). Instantiate in parent. do `[(formGroup)]="formGroup"`. validation will work then.

Comment: Do you guys have any working example of this? Stackblitz would be awesome :-)

Answer (score 0):

you might want to create two separate steppers and use *ngIf to switch between them

```
<mat-vertical-stepper *ngIf="verticalFlag">
  <mat-step>
  </mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>

<mat-horizontal-stepper *ngIf="!verticalFlag">
  <mat-step>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Comment: But stepper steps have so much html code I can't repeat that.

Comment: I guess it is not possible to change the directive programmatically, if that is the case, this is the only choice you have, however, to make it more readable you create a new component i.e stepper.component and separate stepper's code with the rest of the code.

Comment: It's funny, the Material sidenav has a mode. Over, Side, etc.. And this is something I switch based on a break point. But I can't do that with the stepper. I wish I could and maybe submitting a feature request is an option, however until then I like the idea of creating my own component which has a mode. I switch between horiz and vert stepper on my own and simply use content projection and inputs to get my data in.

Comment: looks like someone already suggested this.
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7700

Comment: How would you link the two steppers ? like when the flag changes .. be on the same step ?

Comment: i do this but instead of using `*ngIf`  i use `class="d-none d-md-block" ` this way i create a responsive stepper

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Directionality } from '@angular/cdk/bidi';
import { CdkStep, StepperSelectionEvent } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, ContentChildren, ElementRef, EventEmitter, forwardRef, Inject, Input, Optional, Output, QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { MatStep, MatStepper } from '@angular/material';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

const MAT_STEPPER_PROXY_FACTORY_PROVIDER = {
    provide: MatStepper,
    deps: [forwardRef(() => StepperComponent), [new Optional(), Directionality], ChangeDetectorRef, [new Inject(DOCUMENT)]],
    useFactory: MAT_STEPPER_PROXY_FACTORY
};

export function MAT_STEPPER_PROXY_FACTORY(component: StepperComponent, directionality: Directionality,
    changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, docuement: Document) {
    // We create a fake stepper primarily so we can generate a proxy from it.  The fake one, however, is used until 
    // our view is initialized.  The reason we need a proxy is so we can toggle between our 2 steppers 
    // (vertical and horizontal) depending on  our "orientation" property.  Probably a good idea to include a polyfill 
    // for the Proxy class: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/proxy-polyfill.

    const elementRef = new ElementRef(document.createElement('mat-horizontal-stepper'));
    const stepper = new MatStepper(directionality, changeDetectorRef, elementRef, document);
    return new Proxy(stepper, {
        get: (target, property) => Reflect.get(component.stepper || target, property),
        set: (target, property, value) => Reflect.set(component.stepper || target, property, value)
    });
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-stepper',
    // templateUrl: './stepper.component.html',
    // styleUrls: ['./stepper.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    providers: [MAT_STEPPER_PROXY_FACTORY_PROVIDER],
    template: `
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="orientation">
    <mat-horizontal-stepper *ngSwitchCase="'horizontal'"
                            [labelPosition]="labelPosition"
                            [linear]="linear"
                            [selected]="selected"
                            [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex"
                            (animationDone)="animationDone.emit($event)"
                            (selectionChange)="selectionChange.emit($event)">
    </mat-horizontal-stepper>


    <mat-vertical-stepper *ngSwitchDefault
                            [linear]="linear"
                            [selected]="selected"
                            [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex"
                            (animationDone)="animationDone.emit($event)"
                            (selectionChange)="selectionChange.emit($event)">
    </mat-vertical-stepper>
</ng-container>
`
})
export class StepperComponent {
    // public properties
    @Input() labelPosition?: 'bottom' | 'end';
    @Input() linear?: boolean;
    @Input() orientation?: 'horizontal' | 'vertical';
    @Input() selected?: CdkStep;
    @Input() selectedIndex?: number;

    // public events
    @Output() animationDone = new EventEmitter<void>();
    @Output() selectionChange = new EventEmitter<StepperSelectionEvent>();

    // internal properties
    @ViewChildren(MatStepper) stepperList!: QueryList<MatStepper>;
    @ContentChildren(MatStep) steps!: QueryList<MatStep>;
    get stepper(): MatStepper { return this.stepperList && this.stepperList.first; }

    // private properties
    private lastSelectedIndex?: number;
    private needsFocus = false;

    // public methods
    constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.reset();
        this.stepperList.changes.subscribe(() => this.reset());
        this.selectionChange.subscribe((e: StepperSelectionEvent) => this.lastSelectedIndex = e.selectedIndex);
    }
    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        if (this.needsFocus) {
            this.needsFocus = false;
            const { _elementRef, _keyManager, selectedIndex } = <any>this.stepper;
            _elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
            _keyManager.setActiveItem(selectedIndex);
        }
    }

    // private properties
    private reset() {
        const { stepper, steps, changeDetectorRef, lastSelectedIndex } = this;
        stepper.steps.reset(steps.toArray());
        stepper.steps.notifyOnChanges();
        if (lastSelectedIndex) {
            stepper.selectedIndex = lastSelectedIndex;
        }

        Promise.resolve().then(() => {
            this.needsFocus = true;
            changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Using as it is it gives `No provider for CdkStepper!` and now DOCUMENT comes from angular/common.

Answer (score 0):

here is how i did there is two ways one is using css property and another is using fxLayout which angular provide. so its same i hope you will know how to use css so i will show you how to make using fxLayout. you can check out about fxLayout in *https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs*

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<mat-horizontal-stepper linear fxHide.lt-md>
          <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" editable="true">
            <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
              <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                <input matInput formControlName="firstCtrl" placeholder="Last name, First name" required>
              </mat-form-field>
              <div>
                <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </mat-step>
          <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" editable="true">
            <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
              <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your address</ng-template>
              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Address</mat-label>
                <input matInput formControlName="secondCtrl" placeholder="Ex. 1 Main St, New York, NY"
                       required>
              </mat-form-field>
              <div>
                <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
                <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </mat-step>
          <mat-step>
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
            <p>You are now done.</p>
            <div>
              <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
              <button mat-button (click)="done()">done</button>
            </div>
          </mat-step>
        </mat-horizontal-stepper>
        
        
        
        
        <mat-vertical-stepper linear fxHide.gt-sm>
          <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" editable="true">
            <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
              <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                <input matInput formControlName="firstCtrl" placeholder="Last name, First name" required>
              </mat-form-field>
              <div>
                <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </mat-step>
          <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" editable="true">
            <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
              <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your address</ng-template>
              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Address</mat-label>
                <input matInput formControlName="secondCtrl" placeholder="Ex. 1 Main St, New York, NY"
                       required>
              </mat-form-field>
              <div>
                <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
                <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </mat-step>
          <mat-step>
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
            <p>You are now done.</p>
            <div>
              <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
              <button mat-button (click)="done()">done</button>
            </div>
          </mat-step>
        </mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to duplicate your templates.
Implement the screen size checker from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52989737/5468463, and then:

HTML:

```
<mat-stepper [orientation]="orientation">
...
```

Typescript:

```
...
    orientation: StepperOrientation = "horizontal";
...
    breakpointObserver.observe([
      Breakpoints.XSmall,
      Breakpoints.Small
    ]).subscribe(result => {
      this.orientation = result.matches ? 'vertical' : 'horizontal';
    })
```