# Different Html-Tag based on condition or reuse the the structure

Tags: javascript, css, angular, html, typescript

Hello i'm currently working with Angular Materials Steppers.
I want to change my horizontal Stepper to a vertical Stepper on lower screen widths. My current Approach is using 2 ngif but then everything inside my Steppers is redundant. Is there a way to either change the html tag from

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

to

```
<mat-vertical-stepper>
```

or reuse the inside of my steppers

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper>
 <!-- html-Stuff-->
</mat-horizontal-stepper>

<mat-vertical-stepper>
 <!--the same html-Stuff-->
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

i rather wouldnt want to make an extra-component just for the steppers

Comment: If you want to do the sam in the same page, you can leverage `ng-template`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pasting same HTML code over and over again make it `template` and you can use `ng-container` `ngTemplateOutlet` `ng-template` :

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper>
    <!-- html-Stuff-->
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stepperContent"></ng-container>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>

<mat-vertical-stepper>
    <!--the same html-Stuff-->
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="stepperContent"></ng-container>
</mat-vertical-stepper>


<ng-template #stepperContent>
    <!-- html-Stuff-->
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Your answer lead me to the right direction. Unfortunately  according to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51305909/how-to-pass-a-template-inside-mat-stepper) this is a common problem and cant be solved without Code replication